# External Viewer Preview of Mac cannot find .pdf file

Tags: texmaker, mac, viewers

I would like to use preview from Mac to as external viewer using texmaker. However, when texmaker is running preview(.app) he seems to struggle, finally a preview popup appears: "The file “mscLiterature.pdf” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

It appears that my .pdf doesn't exist. However, when looking for it through the Finder I see that the file has been created. These are the compile sequences I've tested:

- PDFLatex ViewPDF
- Latex dvipdfm View PDF
- Latex dvips ps2pdf View PDF

The box "Don't launch a new instance..." is unticked, so is "Use a "build"..." .

Who has experience using preview and texmaker and may help me with the settings? Regards, Hubert

Comment: Can you open the .pdf file from `Finder` using `preview`?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you marked "external viewer" and simply set the viewer command to

> `open %.pdf`

This will start the program which is assigned by the OS to open PDF files (which usually is Preview).

If you are using another default PDF viewer (e.g. the excellent Skim), you can explicitly tell `open` to start the Preview binary:

> `open -a/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview %.pdf`