# how to launch skim from auctex on mac os?

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launching an external PDF viewer from Emacs/AUCTeX on a Mac OSX fails.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/launching-an-external-pdf-viewer-from-emacs-auctex-on-a-mac-osx-fails)

I am using emacs 24.2.1 with mac os (Mountain Lion).
I am using auctex to edit my latex document.
I do not have evince in my mac and installed skim instead.
To launch an external viewer from my auctex View command(C-c C-c), I add the following line in my .emacs file.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlated-mode) 
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'latex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
         '("%q" skim-make-url))))
(defun skim-make-url () (concat
    (TeX-current-line)
    " \""
    (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
        (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file)))
    "\" \" "
    (buffer-file-name)
"\""));
(setq TeX-view-program-list
  '(("Skim" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %q")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Skim")))
; *** end adding pdf viewer skim**
```

When I trigger View command(C-c C-c), it says complains "No mathing viewer found".

The skim has been installed properly.

Comment: This question asks the same thing : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/launching-an-external-pdf-viewer-from-emacs-auctex-on-a-mac-osx-fails