# Emacs AUCTeX View command

Tags: emacs, auctex, mac, viewers

I need help using the `View` command in AUCTeX running in Emacs. This is essential for viewing PDFs and without it I can not make TeX documents. In my `.emacs` file I have the following (which was created by `M-x customize-variable`):

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Preview" "\"open -a Preview.app %o\""))))
```

Now I open up a `.tex` document and enter `C-c C-c` (I have already compiled):

Emacs gives: `Command: (default View)`

I hit enter

Emacs gives this default command: `View command: dvi2tty -q -w 132`

I hit enter and Emacs says: `View: done.` but displays nothing in a PDF reader!

`dvi2tty` is intended for text only devices, and the command actually creates a new buffer in Emacs which attempts to display the PDF file (it is very messy). Anyway, if I replace `dvi2tty -q -w 132` with `open -a Preview.app %o' (I am running Mac os X 10.8.4 and Preview is the name of the default PDF reader) then Preview opens the PDF!

1. How do I change the default `View command` from `dvi2tty -q -w 132` to `open -a Preview.app %o`?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried hitting `C-c C-v`?

Comment: I wonder if your issue has something to do with the escaped \". I checked my .emacs file, and the only difference I see (besides my pdf viewer) is that I don't have the escaped quotes.

Comment: @dustin `C-c C-v` runs the `View` command without showing what is actually being executed.

Comment: Does open the `pdf` for you though?

Comment: @Anthony there are a few other variables that are all related. I did `C-h v RET TeX- TAB` to get a list of possible completions and then searched for `view`.

Comment: @dustin `C-c C-v` leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: `'(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))))`  Here is my set up try changing the viewer to yours to see if it works.

Comment: I am running OS X and I do not think I have Okular. Anyway, I finally figured it out (see my answer).

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus where did you get AUCTeX? Which version are you running? AFAICS, `dvi2tty` has never been the default viewer in AUCTeX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got lucky and found a solution!

Follow these steps

1. `M-x customize-variable`
2. Emacs gives: `Customize variable:` Enter: `TeX-command-list`
3. Search for `View` (enter `C-s` and then type `View)
4. Emacs will take you to the view command where you can enter text.

It will look something like this (after Command there will be a place for text entry):

```
[INS] [DEL] Name: View                                                                                 
            Command: open -a Preview.app %s.pdf                                                        
            How: [Value Menu] TeX-run-command                                                          
            Create a process for NAME using COMMAND to process FILE. More                              
            Prompt: [Toggle]  on (non-nil)                                                             
            Modes: [Value Menu] All                                                                    
            Menu elements:                                                                             
            [INS] [DEL] Lisp expression: :help                                                         
            [INS] [DEL] Lisp expression: "Run Text viewer"
```

Change the text after `Command:` to whatever you need. This will automatically change your `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: The last sentence is not true. Such changes are placed in the `customizations.el` file and invoked on start up.

Comment: @AndrewSwann When I used the above mentioned sequence of commands and finished with C-x C-s, emacs said it is saving to .emacs

Comment: @YairDaon Indeed, this is dependent on your emacs implementation and set-up.  I now see my remark was based on Aquamacs, which I was using at the time.  The general save location is the value of `custom-file`, which may or may not be your init file, which in turn may or may not be `.emacs`.

Answer (score 5):

The following examples include AUCTeX and non-AUCTeX methods for generating a `*.pdf` document on Windows and OSX, and displaying the `*.pdf` file in a viewer defined by the user.

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; LATEXMK and AUCTEX ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911

;; Sample `latexmkrc` for OSX that copies the *.pdf file from the `/tmp` directory
;; to the working directory:
;;    $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S && (cp "%D" "%R.pdf")';
;;    $pdf_mode = 1;
;;    $out_dir = '/tmp';"

;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
;; option -b highlights the current line
;; option -g opens Skim in the background
;; option -o open Skim in the foreground with full application focus.

;; Skim -- turn on auto-refresh by typing the following into the terminal:
;; defaults write -app Skim SKAutoReloadFileUpdate -boolean true

;; TexLive on OSX:
;; (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))

(eval-after-load "tex" '(progn

  (setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.texlive/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-darwin"))

  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-predicate-list-builtin '(output-pdf t))

  (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(tex-file-name)" (lambda ()
    (concat "\"" (with-current-buffer TeX-command-buffer buffer-file-name) "\""))))

  (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(pdf-file-name)" (lambda ()
    (concat
      "\"" (car (split-string (with-current-buffer TeX-command-buffer buffer-file-name) "\\.tex"))
      ".pdf" "\""))))

  (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(line-number)" (lambda ()
    (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))))

  (cond

    ((eq system-type 'darwin)

      (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(latexmkrc-osx)" (lambda () "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.latexmkrc")))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("latexmk-osx" "latexmk -r %(latexmkrc-osx) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(skim)" (lambda () "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline")))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("Skim" "%(skim) -g %(line-number) %(pdf-file-name) %(tex-file-name)" TeX-run-TeX nil t))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list '("skim-viewer" "%(skim) -g %(line-number) %(pdf-file-name) %(tex-file-name)"))

      (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "skim-viewer"))))

    ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)

      (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(latexmkrc-nt)" (lambda () "y:/.0.data/.0.emacs/.latexmkrc-nt")))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("latexmk-nt" "latexmk -r %(latexmkrc-nt) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list '("%(sumatra)" (lambda () "\"c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\"")))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list '("SumatraPDF" "%(sumatra) -reuse-instance -forward-search %(tex-file-name) %(line-number) %(pdf-file-name)" TeX-run-TeX nil t))

      (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list '("sumatra-viewer" "%(sumatra) -reuse-instance -forward-search %(tex-file-name) %(line-number) %(pdf-file-name)")) 

      (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "sumatra-viewer")))))  ))

(defun auctex-latexmk ()
"Compile, view *.pdf, and clean (maybe)."
(interactive)
  (require 'tex)
  (require 'latex)
  (let ((TeX-PDF-mode t)
        (TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
        (TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex) 
        (TeX-source-correlate-start-server nil)
        (TeX-clean-confirm t))
    (when (buffer-modified-p)
      (save-buffer))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file)
        (lambda (p e)
          (when (not (= 0 (process-exit-status p)))
            (TeX-next-error t) )
          (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (delete-other-windows)
            (TeX-command "View" 'TeX-active-master 0)
            ;; `set-process-sentinel` cannot be used on Windows XP for post-view cleanup,
            ;; because Emacs treats SumatraPDF as an active process until SumatraPDF exits.
            (let ((major-mode 'latex-mode))
              (with-current-buffer TeX-command-buffer
                (TeX-command "Clean" 'TeX-master-file))))))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; LATEXMK START-PROCESS ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(defun combined-latexmk-function ()
(interactive)
  (cond
    ((eq system-type 'darwin)
      (latexmk))
    ((eq system-type 'windows-nt)
      (xp-latexmk) )))

(defun xp-latexmk ()
".latexmkrc contains the following entries:
  $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S';
  $pdf_mode = 1;
  $recorder = 0;
  $clean_ext = 'synctex.gz synctex.gz(busy) aux fdb_latexmk log';"
(interactive)
  (lexical-let* (
      (latexmk-tex-file buffer-file-name)
      (latexmk-base-file (car (split-string buffer-file-name "\\.tex")))
      (latexmk-w32-tex-file (concat "\"" buffer-file-name "\""))
      (latexmk-w32-pdf-file (concat "\"" latexmk-base-file ".pdf" "\""))
      (latexmk-line (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))
      (latexmk-sumatra "c:/Program Files/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe")
      (latexmk-w32-document (concat
        "-reuse-instance"
          " "
        "-forward-search"
          " "
        latexmk-w32-tex-file
          " "
        latexmk-line
          " "
        latexmk-w32-pdf-file))
      (latexmk-tex-output (concat "*" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "*") )
      (latexmk-pl "c:/texlive/2013/bin/win32/latexmk.exe")
      (latexmk-latexmkrc "y:/.0.data/.0.emacs/.latexmkrc-nt") )
    (if (buffer-modified-p)
      (save-buffer))
    (delete-other-windows)
    (set-window-buffer (split-window-horizontally) (get-buffer-create latexmk-tex-output))
    (with-current-buffer latexmk-tex-output (erase-buffer))
    ;; `-reuse-instance` seems to be working very nicely, so no need to kill prior instance.
    ;; (start-process "tskill" nil "c:/WINDOWS/system32/tskill.exe" "SumatraPDF")
    (set-process-sentinel 
      (start-process "deep-clean" nil latexmk-pl "-C" "-r" latexmk-latexmkrc latexmk-tex-file)
      (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (set-process-sentinel 
          (start-process "compile" latexmk-tex-output latexmk-pl "-r" latexmk-latexmkrc latexmk-tex-file)
          (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (when (get-buffer-process (get-buffer latexmk-tex-output))
              (process-kill-without-query (get-buffer-process
                (get-buffer latexmk-tex-output))))
            (kill-buffer latexmk-tex-output)
            (delete-other-windows)
            (switch-to-buffer (get-file-buffer latexmk-tex-file))
            (w32-shell-execute "open" latexmk-sumatra latexmk-w32-document)
            (sit-for 1)
            (start-process "clean" nil latexmk-pl "-c" "-r" latexmk-latexmkrc latexmk-tex-file)))))))))

(defun latexmk-process-filter (proc string)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (with-current-buffer (messages-buffer)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (when (not (bolp))
        (insert "\n"))
      (insert string)
      (when (not (bolp))
        (insert "\n")))
    (when (string-match "?" string)
      (display-buffer (messages-buffer))
      (with-current-buffer (messages-buffer)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (walk-windows
          (lambda (window)
            (when (string-equal (buffer-name (window-buffer window)) "*Messages*")
              (set-window-point window (point-max))))
          nil t)))))

(defun latexmk ()
  ".latexmkrc contains the following entries (WITHOUT the four backslashes):
  $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S && (cp \"%D\" \"%R.pdf\")';
  $pdf_mode = 1;
  $out_dir = '/tmp';"
(interactive)
  (lexical-let* (
      (latexmk-tex-file buffer-file-name)
      (latexmk-pdf-file (concat "/tmp/"
        (car (split-string (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "\\.tex")) ".pdf"))
      (latexmk-line (format "%d" (line-number-at-pos)))
      (latexmk-skim "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline")
      (latexmk-pl "/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl")
      (latexmk-latexmkrc "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.latexmkrc")
      (latexmk-close-skim-window (concat
        "set myWindowTitle to \"" (file-name-nondirectory latexmk-pdf-file) "\"\n"
        "tell application \"System Events\"\n"
        "tell application \"Skim\" to close (every window whose name contains myWindowTitle)\n"
        "end tell")) )
    (when (buffer-modified-p)
      (save-buffer))
    (when (not (one-window-p t))
      (delete-other-windows))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "close-window" nil "osascript" "-e" latexmk-close-skim-window)
      (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (set-process-sentinel
          (start-process "deep-clean" nil latexmk-pl "-C" "-r" latexmk-latexmkrc latexmk-tex-file)
          (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
            (when (get-process "compile")
              (delete-process (get-process "compile")))
            (start-process "compile" nil latexmk-pl "-r" latexmk-latexmkrc latexmk-tex-file)
            (set-process-filter (get-process "compile") 'latexmk-process-filter)
            (set-process-sentinel
              (get-process "compile")
              (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                (set-process-sentinel
                  (start-process "displayline" nil latexmk-skim latexmk-line latexmk-pdf-file latexmk-tex-file)
                  (lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
                    (when (not (one-window-p t))
                      (delete-other-windows))))))))))))))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: Please don't keep an edit list, simply update your question to reflect the best content. An edit list isn't very readable and there is no need for it because there is an [automatic history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/156617/revisions) for every post. Also note, that if you edit your own answer to ofter (15 times I think) it will turn into a *Community Wiki* automatically. Then everyone can edit it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall where I found the following code, but: To make auctex call pdflatex by default and to preview pdf files using okular, I put the following at the end of my `~/.xemacs/init.el` file:

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(defun pdfevince ()
   (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
                 '("^pdf$" "." "evince %o %(outpage)")))

(defun pdfokular ()
   (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
                 '("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)")))

;(add-hook  'LaTeX-mode-hook  'pdfevince  t) ; AUCTeX LaTeX mode
(add-hook  'LaTeX-mode-hook  'pdfokular  t) ; AUCTeX LaTeX mode
```

If you prefer evince to okular, uncomment the second to last line and comment out the last line.  That's for xemacs; for emacs, I suppose you put it into your .emacs file.