# Adding an option to the PDFLaTeX call from AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

In my `.emacs` I have

```
'(TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

set. So I'm using PDFLaTeX. I'm not sure why this is not the default these days.
I had also set

```
'(LaTeX-command "latex -shell-escape")
```

In hindsight this was a bad idea, but I didn't realise it till 
I was trying to get SyncTeX to work, but it wouldn't.
I belatedly realized that because I had set LaTeX-command manually,
I was overwriting the

```
--synctex=1
```

option that would normally have been there.

Which brings to my question.

1. Is `LaTeX-command` the right command to modify to add the
   `-shell-escape` option, and if so
2. What is the right way to add an option to `LaTeX-command`?

@David Carlisle suggested

```
(setq LaTeX-command (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape"))
```

which seems to be in the right ballpark, but this gives the error:

```
 Symbol's value as variable is void: LaTeX-command
```

NOTE: Evaluating `LaTeX-command` just gives "latex", so this may not be the right thing to append to.

Comment: The following works for me: `'(LaTeX-command "latex -shell-escape -synctex=1")`.

Comment: @Philipp The idea is to just add `-shell-escape` to whatever is already in `LaTeX-command` (if that is the right command to change).

Comment: When you get an error like `Symbol's value as variable is void: something-or-other`, it usually means the library containing the definition of that particular variable hasn't been loaded yet.  In this case, the variable `LaTeX-command` is in the library `tex.el`.  So whenever you want to redefine a variable in a particular library and avoid an error message like the one you got, you can do something like:  `(eval-after-load "tex" '(progn (setq LaTeX-command (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape")) ))`  You would use `progn` when more than one entry.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911

Comment: @FaheemMitha Are you still looking for an answer? Are you interested in a per-document way to set the LaTeX command?

Comment: @giordano I suppose I am. I haven't checked lawlist's answer yet, though. Sure, I'd be interested in a per-document way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Starting from version 11.88 of AUCTeX, you can add an option to the TeX processor with the file-local variable `TeX-command-extra-options`:

```
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
```

As [explained in the manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Processor-Options.html#index-TeX_002dcommand_002dextra_002doptions), you have to manually make this variable safe as a local variable because of the security holes it can open.

**Note:** this question inspired me to add this feature.

---

Until version 11.87, AUCTeX hadn't a facility to add easily an option to the compiler (at least I always missed to find it).  I see at least three strategies you can follow:

1. edit `LaTeX-command-style` (the suggested way if you want to activate shell escape for all documents)
2. add a new element to `TeX-engine-alist`
3. add a new element to `TeX-command-list`

I'll try to outline 1 and 2.  3 is similar to 2 in spirit.

**Note:** in a previous version of the answer I suggested to edit `LaTeX-command`, but that variable should be reserved to the actual `latex` binary name.  Setting it to `latex -shell-escape` doesn't play well with forward/inverse search (for the curious person: `TeX-source-correlate-determine-method` would fail because there is no `latex -shell-escape` binary and so forward/inverse search would fall back on source specials, even if SyncTeX is actually available).

---

## `LaTeX-command-style`

This variable allows to change the options passed to the compiler, its syntax is a bit cumbersome, though.  In addition, this isn't a file local variable so you can't set (by default) it on a per-document basis.

#### The customize way

Issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `LaTeX-command-style` <kbd>RET</kbd>.  In the `String` field of the variable add `-shell-escape` after `%(latex)`.  E.g., if the value of the field is

```
%(PDF)%(latex) %S%(PDFout)"
```

change it into

```
%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)"
```

#### The do-it-for-me way

Add the following code to your `.emacs`.

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)")))
```

---

## `TeX-engine-alist`

Insert a new element, called for example `default-shell-escape`, similar to the `default` element of `TeX-engine-alist-builtin`.  You can do it by using the customization interface or adding an Elisp code to your `.emacs`.

After creating this new engine, you'll be able to activate it by using the menu `Command > TeXing Options > Use Default with shell escape`.  If you want to set it by default for all documents or on a per-document basis see below.

#### The customize way

Issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-engine-alist` <kbd>RET</kbd>.  Press the `INS` button and fill the fields in the following way:

- Symbol: `default-shell-escape`
- Name: `Default with shell escape`
- Plain TeX command: `tex -shell-escape`
- LaTeX command: `latex -shell-escape`
- ConTeXt command: leave empty

#### The do-it-for-me way

Add the following code to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list
      'TeX-engine-alist
      '(default-shell-escape "Default with shell escape"
     "pdftex -shell-escape"
     "pdflatex -shell-escape"
     ConTeXt-engine))
     ;; (setq-default TeX-engine 'default-shell-escape)
     ))
```

### Set the `default-shell-escape` engine as default

Now you can set the new fictitious engine as default for all documents

1. by customizing `TeX-engine` (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-varaiable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-engine` <kbd>RET</kbd>) and selecting `Default with shell escape` in the drop-down `Value Menu`, or
2. by uncommenting (ie, removing `;;` at the beginning of) the

```lisp
(setq TeX-engine 'default-shell-escape)
```

line in the previous Elisp code.

### Use the `default-shell-escape` engine on a per-document basis

Alternatively, you can leave the default engine as it is and pick up the `default-shell-escape` engine only in the documents in which you actually need it.  In those documents, issue <kbd>M-x</kbd> `add-file-local-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `TeX-engine`  `default-shell-escape` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: Hi giordano. Sorry about being so slow in responding to this. I guess it fell off my radar. I tried `(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (setq LaTeX-command (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape"))))`, but this seemed to remove synctex as well for some reason. Without it I get `Running `LaTeX' on `corrmodel' with ``pdflatex --synctex=1
-interaction=nonstopmode "\input" corrmodel.tex''`. With it I get `Running `LaTeX' on `corrmodel' with ``pdflatex -shell-escape
-src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" corrmodel.tex''`. Can you reproduce?

Comment: I thought this might be caused by something in my .emacs file, but I stripped it down to basics, and I still get the same result.

Comment: I'm unclear on the difference between "TeX-engine-alist::The do-it-for-me way" and "Set the default-shell-escape engine as default". I'm particularly fuzzy on why you would uncomment the `(setq TeX-engine 'default-shell-escape)` in the earlier code.

Comment: @FaheemMitha after adding that code, did you restart Emacs?  I always give it for granted, but this is needed to make changes effective.

Comment: Yes, I always make a point of restarting emacs after every change. Note also that I'm using the Debian auctex package here.

Comment: Ok, good.  What upsets me most is that with `(eval-after-load "tex" '(progn (setq LaTeX-command (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape"))))` you lose SyncTeX support.  Without other changes that shouldn't happen and changing `LaTeX-command` should be the easiest way to accomplish what you want.  Try removing (i.e., commenting) all other customization about AUCTeX and insert in your `.emacs` only the above `eval-after-load`.

Comment: The `(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list
      'TeX-engine-alist
      '(default-shell-escape "Default with shell escape"
     (concat TeX-command " -shell-escape")
     (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape")
     ConTeXt-engine))
     (setq TeX-engine 'default-shell-escape)
     ))` code doesn't have any effect at all, with or without `(setq TeX-engine 'default-shell-escape)` commented out.

Comment: In addition to `(eval-after-load "tex" '(progn (setq LaTeX-command (concat LaTeX-command " -shell-escape"))))` I only have `(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-start-server t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` in my code. That looks like it should be harmless.

Comment: Do you feel like doing this in a chat room? These comments are awkward. If now is not good for you, we can do it another time.

Comment: Ok, let's go for a chat.

Comment: Do you want to use the main chat room, or the special chat room?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14170/discussion-between-giordano-and-faheem-mitha)

Comment: @FaheemMitha  I updated the answer `:-)`.

Comment: I haven't gone through the rest of the options, but the latex command style thing works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

To summarize the answer by @giordano for use by an Elisp beginner, you should add this to the bottom of your TeX document:

```
% Local Variables:
% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
% End:
```

And you should add this to your init-file:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tex
  (add-to-list 'safe-local-variable-values
               '(TeX-command-extra-options . "-shell-escape")))
```

To make the changes take effect without restarting Emacs, you should run `M-: (load user-init-file) RET` and then type `M-x normal-mode` in your TeX buffer.

Note that this change to your init-file means that compiling malicious TeX code using AUCTeX **can run arbitrary shell commands**, so be careful.