# Help compiling with XeLaTeX. A few errors

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to compile a document with XeLaTeX. The document is a beamer document created from the template of the theme

```
\usetheme[titleprogressbar]{m}
```

that `OverLeaf` provides. I was trying to compile it with AucTeX, fixing the `Use Xetex` engine, but it throws and error. If I compile from the terminal using `xelatex` it throws a bunch of error messages, but if I skip through all of them with enter, it produces me the right pdf, without any weird thing. I would like some help understanding them to see how to compile it with auctex.

The first one is this.

```
Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

))

! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
```

Why does this happen?

Then it asks me to provide a file:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `project.pyg' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: pyg)

Enter file name:
```

I don't know what file this is supposed to be, and it wasn't there in the `git clone` from `overleaf`.

That's it, if I just ignore it, it gives me the pdf I want.

Calling `xelatex -shell-escape project.pdf` works, but my problem is making it work with AucTex.

Comment: That's what the error says: you need to pass the `-shell-escape` command line option.

Comment: Yes, and if I do so, it just works. But why is it not working with auctex? Is there anything needed not activated by default?

Comment: the minted program needs to call the external python program pygmentize to syntax highlight the code listings. Such calls are not allowed unless you specify `-shell-escape`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. Thank you. So if I were using any code listings the output shouldn't be right, I guess. Is the shell-escape flag not activated in auctex by default?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157242/adding-an-option-to-the-pdflatex-call-from-auctex It's about PDFLaTeX, but it applies to XeLaTeX as well.

Comment: It would not make sense to activate `-shell-escape` by default, the whole point is that external programs are prevented for security reasons unless you explicitly allow them

Comment: If you don't have code listings why are you loading `minted` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have no idea. I said it was part of a template I saw and liked. I don't thing I will use listings. If I remove the inclussiong of the package, then it produces a different error. I can compile it through the terminal but the word `trac` appears in the top of the first frame. The `m` theme must be using it for something, I guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, forget it, it was using it a little bit later. If I just remove everything related to it, I can compile it without the flag. The danger of templates.

Thank you for the help