# No plot lines with TiKz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot

I'm following [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/andler-optimal-lot-size/) and [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/) example that supposedly is using gnuplot. First, I'm getting results (U15.10, gnuplot 4.6.6, Emacs 24.5, latest Ubuntu texlive) from simply pasting the code into Emacs and hitting "Latex". It produces many files, including a pdf. But upon viewing the pdf I see everything plotted well but the actual plot lines. Not sure what this means or how to correct. Also, how does this involve gnuplot? I don't see it being called.

Comment: You need to compile with `shell-escape` enabled to allow for the call to `gnuplot`. I'm not sure how to do that from emacs, but in a terminal you want something like `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked from the command line. And [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157242/adding-an-option-to-the-pdflatex-call-from-auctex) seemed to clear up the problem by adding `(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape %S%(PDFout)")))` to my init.