# Using externalize with standalones for tikz figures? - (output-directory and tikzexternalize)

Tags: texstudio, standalone, tikz-external, shell-escape, externalize

I am using TexStudio on Mac with texlive 2016. For my tikz figures I use ktikz and matlab2tikz. Some matlab plots have quite a few data points, therefore I decided to use standalones for all my tikz figures and wanted to use externalize (**which is not working**).

To keep my main folder clean I use a `build` folder and set the following `pdflatex` command (Preferences -> Commands):

`/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./build %.tex`

Also the `BibTex` command had to be adjusted:

`/Library/TeX/texbin/bibtex build/%.aux`

Then I had to use additional search paths (Preferences -> Build -> Show Advances Options -> Log File and Pdf File):

```
Log File: ./build
Pdf File: ./build
Commands ($PATH): /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

Every time I use `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize` I get the following error although I have `-shell-escape` option added to the `pdflatex` command.

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./tikz_figures/main-figure0" "\def\tikzex
ternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file './tik
z_figures/main-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify 
that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-esca
pe'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the
 command simply failed? Error messages can be found in './tikz_figures/main-fig
ure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

**Is there something worng with my path setup or the prefix option to `\tikzexternalize`?**

Commenting the two lines `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize` it works.

---

---

## Edit

## MWE

**main.tex** (folder: ./)

```
\documentclass{report}

% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\graphicspath{
    {./figures/tikz/}{./figures/non_tikz/}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write1 -shell-escape, prefix=./build/]
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./build/tikz_figures/]
%\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{standalone}
%\input{./figures/tikz/tikz_definitions}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{example}
\caption{example caption.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**example.tikz** (folder: ./figures/tikz/)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% draw help lines
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1\textwidth,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

**example.tex** (folder: ./figures/tikz/)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{tikz_definitions}

\begin{document}
\input{example.tikz}
\end{document}
```

No matter which prefix or options I use for `\tikzexternalize` I get the same error message.

---

**Additional information:**

Here is the folder structuer that I use:

```
main folder
    main.tex (main tex file)
    references.bib
    build (folder)
        epstopdf (folder)
        tikz_figures (folder
        *.aux, *.log, *.pdf, *.toc, (output files)
    chapters (folder)
        *.tex (tex files)
    figures (folder)
        non_tikz (folder)
            *.png, *.jpg, (all non tikz figures)
        tikz (folder)
            blocks (folder containing figures for tikz figures)
            *.tex (multiple standalone tex files)
            *.tikz (multiple tikz files editable with ktiz)
            tikz_definitions.tex (one tikz definition file)
```

### ----------

**even more information**

**non MWE**

The preamble of my **main.tex** file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, openright,12pt]{report}

\graphicspath{
    {./figures/tikz/}{./figures/non_tikz/}
}
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write1 -shell-escape, prefix=./build/]
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./tikz_figures/]
%\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{standalone}
\input{./figures/tikz/tikz_definitions}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{example}
\caption{example caption.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}

\end{document}
```

Because `ktikz` cannot handle standard latex packages, I use a template for all the tikz figures. This results in one `tikz_definitions.tex` (template) and a `*.tikz` and a `*.tex` (standalone) for every drawn ktikz figure.

**tikz_definitions.tex**

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\definecolor{oneColor}{RGB}{47,128,0}
\definecolor{secondColor}{RGB}{242,30,0}
\definecolor{thirdColor}{RGB}{106,178,248}

\tikzstyle{line} = [dash pattern=on 15pt off 25pt]

%% define reusable figure 
\newcommand{\reusablefigure}[4]{
    % a figure
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \node[anchor=center, rotate=#4, opacity=0.6, inner sep=0] 
        (#1) at (#2,#3) {\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{blocks/a_figure.pdf}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    % white background rectangle
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \begin{scope}[shift=(#1.center), rotate=#4]
        \fill [white, rounded corners=10pt] (-1.35,-0.53) rectangle (1.35,0.53);
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    % coordinate frame
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
    \begin{scope}[shift=(#1.center), rotate=#4]
        \draw [<->, thick, color=#1Color] 
            (-0.8,1.1) node [left] (y) {$y_{#1}$} -- 
            (-0.8,0) -- 
            (2,0) node [below right] (x) {$x_{#1}$};
    \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

%% define another reusable figure
\newcommand{\anotherfigure}[2]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
        \draw [fill=red] (#1,#2) circle (0.07cm);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

Here is an example of a figure (consisting of *.tikz and *.tex file)

***example.tikz**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=0.8, 
    axis/.style={very thick, ->, >=stealth'},
]

    % draw lines
    \draw[line, ultra thick] (0.2\textwidth, 4) -- (0.95\textwidth, 4);
    \draw[line, ultra thick] (0.2\textwidth, 2) -- (0.95\textwidth, 2);

    % a figure
    \reusablefigure{name1}{0}{0}{45}

    % the same figure
    \reusablefigure{name2}{10}{3}{0}


    % measurements
    \anotherfigure{1}{1}
    \anotherfigure{2}{2}
    \anotherfigure{4}{3}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

***example.tex**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{tikz_definitions}

\begin{document}
\input{overview.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried starting from a small, minimal example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? For example, your `overview.tikz` need not be so complicated. Just draw a line. You can do away with all your `\newcommands` as well, they (probably)  don't contribute to the externalization process. Once you're done setting up a minimal example which still gives the same error, post it here as an edit.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've added a minimal example resulting in the same error.

Comment: If you still have this problem, check out [ebosi's answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243935/error-using-tikz-externalizecant-write-md5-file/360284#360284). It solved a very similar issue for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
Here is a minimal working example for a simple folder structure like this below. You have to compile the `main.tex` with `pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex`.
With `\tikzsetnextfilename{<...>}` you can set the output name. You have to create the folder `build`(first) manually before compiling.

> main.tex
>
> InputTikz (folder)
>
> ---exampletikz.tex (tikz)
>
> build (folder)

The MWE produces a new folder (OutputTikz) with pdf files(standalone figures) and  `main.aux,main.auxlock,main.txt,main.pdf` are saved in the `build` directory.

> main.tex
>
> InputTikz (folder)
>
> ---exampletikz.tex(tikz)
>
> OutputTikz(folder)
>
> ---testname.pdf(standalone pdf)
>
> ---B_name.pdf(standalone pdf)
>
> build (folder)
>
> ---main.aux
>
> ---main.auxlock
>
> ---main.txt
>
> ---main.pdf

**compilation:**

1. Create the folder build first!
2. Please compile with:
   `pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex`

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./OutputTikz/]    
\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{testname}
\input{InputTikz/exampleTikz}

\tikzsetnextfilename{B_name}
\input{InputTikz/exampleTikz}
\end{document}
```

**exampletikz.tex**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this does not allow the use of an output directory.

Comment: @evolving . Why not? It saved the .tikz figures standalone in the predefind folder -> OutputTikz here ‘\tikzexternalize[prefix=./OutputTikz/] ‘ . Or i am wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the additional `output-directory` option for `pdflatex`. Though, I think this option should still work. However, adding `\tikzsetnextfilename{figurename}` changed the error message. When I try using `\input` or `\includestandalone`, I get: `I can't write on file ./build/tikz_figures/figurename.md5'`.

Comment: I have problems modifying this solution to my folder structure because I would like to use the `output-directory` option.

Comment: One folder for all tikz figures is great but I would like to have another folder for intermediate latex files (build folder). The command I wrote in my question: `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./build %.tex` uses an `output-directory` option for all intermediate latex generated files (aux, log, pdf, ...). Using this option there seems to be some path problems.

Comment: Does the update work for you? You have to create a build folder and to compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex`...

Comment: I tried it using the `-output-directory` option but with the mentioned error message: `I can't write on file ./build/tikz_figures/figurename.md5'`. Is this working for you? Are you using TexStudio?

Comment: No i use Texmaker. Yes my example works. Try my simple example step by step... if its working for you ... you can go on. Clean  old stuff.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried it again using `pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex` and `\tikzexternalize[prefix=./OutputTikz/]` but then I keep getting the error: `I can't write on file ./OutputTikz/figurename.md5'`. Folder structure is as you suggested.

Comment: I noticed that the `*.md5` files are created inside the build folder.

Comment: When I use `\tikzexternalize[prefix=./build/]` and compile, then I first get `system returned with code 256` and the following error: `! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./build/example" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file './build/fig' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please enabled system calls. Error messages can be found in './build/fig.log'.`

Comment: However, the file fig.pdf was created during compilation inside the build folder... Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you try (exact) my example? I  wonder  why 'figurename' and '\tikzexternalrealjob{main} appear in your error... . I didn't use this names... . Use a clean folder.

Comment: @evolving any updates?

Comment: I believe the problem is that for some reason, TikZ tries to combine the `output-directory` and `prefix` paths when creating the `.md5` files - see [ebosi's answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360284/108704) for details. As for why it apparently worked for you - perhaps differences between TeX distributions? I've noticed before that `output-dir` doesn't quite work the same between my installations of TeXLive on Linux and MikTeX on Windows (this specific issue was on Linux, haven't tested Windows yet).

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I've tested it on Windows and it still puts the `.md5` files in the wrong location, but the target directory is created automatically, so there's no error. On Linux I had to create the extra `.\build\build` folder myself. The OP's Mac is probably the same.