# Cannot get Skim to open on C-x C-v

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex

I have been trying to get Skim to start from emacs. I always get no "matching viewer found". Here are the settings of my .emacs and I am sure something is wrong here, but cannot figure it out. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)
(setq command-line-default-directory "~/")
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    (add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
         '("%q" skim-make-url))))
(defun skim-make-url () (concat
    (TeX-current-line)
    " \""
    (expand-file-name (funcall file (TeX-output-extension) t)
        (file-name-directory (TeX-master-file)))
    "\" \""
    (buffer-file-name)"\""))
 ;; This line tells emacs where to find the latex compiler
 (setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/texbin:" (getenv "PATH")))
'(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
(lambda ()
(add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
'("^pdf$" "."
"/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b %q %n %o %b")))
)
 ;; start emacs in server mode so that skim can talk to it
(server-start);
;; This line tells emacs to create pdf files instead of dvi files.
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
(setq TeX-view-program-list
'(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %q   %n %o %b")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
```

Comment: Can you open Skim from the command line using `/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g <filename>.pdf`?

Comment: No I cannot. I get "34:47: syntax error: A unknown token can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)"

Comment: I sorted this out. I actually opened the Auctex settings for Tex-command in emacs and found that for some reason, the Tex command for viewing pdf-output was not set to the PDF Viewer in the .emacs file. I did this manually and now I can open pdfs from emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this out. I actually manually opened the Auctex settings for Tex-command in Emacs and found that for some reason, the Tex command for viewing pdf-output was not set to the PDF Viewer in the .emacs file. I did this manually and now I can open pdfs from emacs. Doing this changed the settings in my .emacs file quite a bit. Below is the extra text that was added by Emacs. I have not had the time to reconcile what I had added manually to the .emacs and what Emacs added. A lot of the text below is actually redundant to pdf viewing and I will clean it up at leisure, but for now everything works.

```
(custom-set-variables
;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
'(TeX-output-view-style (quote (("^pdf$" "." "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents     
 /SharedSupport/displayline %q %n %o %b") ("^dvi$" ("^landscape$" 
 "^pstricks$\\|^pst-\\|^psfrag$") "%(o?)dvips -t landscape %d -o && gv %f") ("^dvi$" 
 "^pstricks$\\|^pst-\\|^psfrag$" "%(o?)dvips %d -o && gv %f") ("^dvi$" ("^\\(?:a4
 \\(?:dutch\\|paper\\|wide\\)\\|sem-a4\\)$" "^landscape$") "%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper a4r 
 -s 0 %d") ("^dvi$" "^\\(?:a4\\(?:dutch\\|paper\\|wide\\)\\|sem-a4\\)$" "%(o?)xdvi 
 %dS -paper a4 %d") ("^dvi$" ("^\\(?:a5\\(?:comb\\|paper\\)\\)$" "^landscape$") 
"%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper a5r -s 0 %d") ("^dvi$" "^\\(?:a5\\(?:comb\\|paper\\)\\)$" 
"%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper a5 %d") ("^dvi$" "^b5paper$" "%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper b5 %d") 
("^dvi$" "^letterpaper$" "%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper us %d") ("^dvi$" "^legalpaper$" 
"%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper legal %d") ("^dvi$" "^executivepaper$" "%(o?)xdvi %dS -paper 
7.25x10.5in %d") ("^dvi$" "." "%(o?)xdvi %dS %d") ("^pdf$" "." "xpdf -remote %s 
-raise %o %(outpage)") ("^html?$" "." "netscape %o"))))
'(TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks output-pdf) "dvips 
 and gv") (output-dvi "xdvi") (output-html "xdg-open") (output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))))
```

Comment: For more ideas regarding how one might go about setting up the user-configuration file for OSX and Windows, here is a link to my setup:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911