# Emacs + Skim + Live Preview?

Tags: emacs, auctex, live-preview

I have been using Latexian for a while, but some of its limitations and my natural tendency to use emacs, is prompting me to take a look at my work environment again (OSX 10.9.2).

I have seen some guides for setting up Skim with Aquamacs and highlight current line in the editor. Which is great. However, is it possible to set this up so that Skim shows a live preview of the PDF? The way one can with Flashmode + TeXShop, or with Latexian?

Comment: You just need the `pvc` option if your using `latexmk` and set Skim to detect changes:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/738755/2112489 The following link contains a sample configuration for AUCTeX -- it uses a latexmkrc file where a -pvc option can be set (e.g., `$preview_continuous_mode = 1`), or it can be set in the command line -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  This assumes the pdf will update in the Skim window on saving the Emacs buffer.  You can also trigger this with every keystroke -- e.g., `post-command-hook`.

Comment: Thanks! Can it be triggered to update every n seconds instead of every keystroke (which will likely be an overkill)?

Comment: For certain actions that do not need the `post-command-hook`, Emacs has idle timers:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html  I personally like manually triggering the update with `save-buffer`, which is the default when using the `-pvc` option.  However, I am not presently using the live update with my current work-flow -- I just press my keyboard combination for save and generate (without using `-pvc`).

Comment: I have been going through the two links you provided. They are immensely helpful. I wish to inquire about a different possibility since your lisp capabilities are far more extensive and current than mine. I want emacs to have the following default behaviour: 1. When it opens a text document (could be tex, fortran, anything), it creates a folder called e-backup in the current directory of the source file, 2. Every 5 minutes, it auto-saves to that folder. Now, your second URL uses /tmp as the out_dir, which means that even the generated PDF file will go to that directory. See followup comment.

Comment: MikTeX allows you to specify an aux directory, but TeXlive on Mac doesn't. I want to use lisp magic + auctex to create a directory named 'aux' in the source directory where all files except .bbl, .pdf, .tex (of course) and .idx (if any) go. Is that possible to manage somehow?

Comment: The code I use (*second* link in first comment) **also** copies the .pdf file over to the working directory every time a compilation occurs -- replacing the old .pdf file with the new one.  The .pdf file that gets displayed in Skim is the one in the `/tmp` directory because it is a little faster that way.  You could change the `/tmp` directory to your new directory where auxiliary files will be stored.  Emacs has a function called `make-directory` which you can use to create your new directory, and set that as the path for auxiliary storage.

Comment: **NOTE**:  The *second* link in the first comment contains three (3) different sample solutions -- one for AUCTeX, one for OSX that does not use AUCTeX, and one for Windows that does not use AUCTeX.  The contents of the `latexmkrc` file described in the doc-string for the Emacs custom *function* named `latexmk` is what I presently use.  The custom Emacs *function* named `latexmk` is of course different than the perl script written by Professor John Collins.  I use the same `latexmkrc` file for the AUCTeX solution and the OSX solution that does *not* use AUCTeX.

Comment: I updated the post in the *second* link set forth in the first comment to highlight the fact that the `latexmkrc` is what performs the magic of copying the *.pdf file over to the working directory during the compilation process, and the sample `latexmkrc` configuration is now at the outset of the post.