# AUCTeX View and Compile commands in Emacs 24.4

Tags: emacs, auctex, viewers

With Emacs 24.3 on Mac OS X, I have used the method described in the answer by CodeKingPlusPlus at
[Emacs AUCTeX View command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119645/emacs-auctex-view-command)
to use C-c C-v to open compiled latex PDFs using Preview.app.

After switching to Emacs 24.4 (but using the same AUCTeX version and .emacs file) it is not working anymore. For C-c C-v now I get the error "No appropriate .dvi file could be found". I thought maybe I need to do `M-x customize-variable` again to set the variable `TeX-command-list`, but this variable doesn't exists anymore.

`C-c C-v` is bound to the command `tex-view`, which, by definition attempts to open a .dvi file. The command invoked seems to be described by the variable `tex-dvi-view-command`, but changing that to `open -a Preview *.pdf` or something similar doesn't help anything. So this may be only for .dvi files, but I don't see any other command for .pdfs.

`C-c C-c` is also working strangely. In 24.3 it offered a command (usually `Compile` or `View`) depending on whether the .tex file needed compilation. Now it always offers `\doc-view`, and any time I want to compile, I need to enter `pd`+`Space`+`Enter` to run `pdflatex`.

Any help with getting Preview to open and making compiling easier would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have one of these in your `LaTeX-mode-hook`?:  `(TeX-PDF-mode t)`  Or, perhaps, the global equivalent?  If not, perhaps you could try one of those.  Also, check out the following settings to see if they are set correctly: `(add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list . . .` and `(setq TeX-view-program-selection . . .`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having just made the same update to Emacs 24.4, I had similar symptoms.  The view prompts are coming from the built in tex mode, not AuCTeX.  Looking at the loading messages, there is a report that `tex-site` could not be found.

The solution for me was to remove auctex and reinstall it.  I had auctex installed via the package system and used that for these operations.  After this, restarting emacs and loading a tex file now loads AuCTeX (most visible by the presence of a Command menu) and viewing and compiling now work as they should.

Comment: Everything worked as you described. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, elisp needs to be recompiled after change of major versions of emacs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725778/how-to-rebuild-elpa-packages-after-upgrade-of-emacs

Comment: @Thomas Excellent pointer.